# mysql - find linked images

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table that stores images and i want to find the 'root' of the links between the images.
For example, this is the table:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| fileID | fileName | fileLinkName | fileLinkID | fileData |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 1      | file1    | None         | None       | BLOBxxx  |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 2      | file2    | file1        | 1          | BLOBxxx  |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 3      | file3    | file2        | 2          | BLOBxxx  |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 4      | file4    | None         | None       | BLOBxxx  |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
| 5      | file5    | file3        | 3          | BLOBxxx  |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

The `fileLinkName` is the name of the `fileName` is it linked to and the `fileLinkID` is the `fileID` it is linked to. Image data is stored in `fileData`.

I need an SQL statement that will show me all of the linked files within this table.
I need an output like this:

```
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
    | fileID | fileName | fileLinkName | fileLinkID | fileData |
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
    | 1      | file1    | None         | None       | BLOBxxx  |
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
    | 2      | file2    | file1        | 1          | BLOBxxx  |
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
    | 3      | file3    | file2        | 2          | BLOBxxx  |
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
    | 5      | file5    | file3        | 3          | BLOBxxx  |
    +--------+----------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

I want to find all of the links between the images.

In the example above:

- file2 is linked to file 1
- file3 is linked to file 2
- file 5 is linked to file 3

Comment: This is called a hierarchical or recursive query.  MySQL does not have built-in support for this type of query (other databases do).  You should do this with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self-join as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a1.fileName,' is linked to file ',a2.fileLinkID)
FROM fileTable a1 
JOIN fileTable a2 ON a1.fileID = a2.fileLinkID 
ORDER BY fileID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check whether the filed is not empty or not NULL:

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `fileLinkID` != NULL OR `fileLinkID` = '';